# Complicated 'IF' function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

In Sheet 1, I have the following:

[image: Sheet 1]

If the Due Date is after the Date Submitted, then I want the value in column D of this sheet to be the Detail Status, which is on Sheet 2,

[image: Sheet 2]

UNLESS the Detail Status is blank, in which case I want column D to say "Due after PV."

I'm not sure how to do this - I need something like an IF, THEN, UNLESS statement, but I don't think anything like this exists. How can I make this formula?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a formatted formula will make the logic easier to follow:

```
=IF(B2>C2,
      IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)="","Due after PV",
           VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)),
"")
```

[image]